# activerecord single table inheritance on ruby 3

Tags: ruby, activerecord, orm, ruby-on-rails-3.2, single-table-inheritance

I have the following classes mapped with STI:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class StudentEmployee < Employee
  # I'd like to keep university only to StudentEmployee...
end
#Just to make this example easier to understand, not using migrations
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
    create_table :employees do |table|
        table.column :name, :string
        table.column :salary, :integer
        table.column :university, :string # Only Students

    end
end

emp = Employee.create(:name=>"Joe",:salary=>20000,:university=>"UCLA")
```

I'd like to prevent the setting of the university field for Employees, but allow it for StudentEmployees. I tried to use attr_protected, but it will only prevent mass setting:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_protected :university
end

class StudentEmployee < Employee
  attr_accessible :university
end
#This time, UCLA will not be assigned here
emp = Employee.create(:name=>"Joe",:salary=>20000,:university=>"UCLA")
emp.university = "UCLA" # but this will assign university to any student...
emp.save
puts "only Students should have univesities, but this guy has one..."+emp.university.to_s
```

The problem here is that it will insert in the database a university for simple employees.
Another problem is that I think it would be better to say in the StudentEmployee class that university is an attribute, and not to say in the Employee that university "is not" a a visible attribute... it just goes in the inverse direction of natural abstraction.

Thanks.

Comment: a way to improve abstraction is state the attributes of Employee and StudentEmployee with attr_accessible. But this will not prevent the user to call the university setter by hand. Perhaps with some combination of private methods? or some change in the ActiveRecord way to deal with absent methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :no_university, unless: lambda { |e| e.type === "StudentEmployee" }
  def no_university
    errors.add :university, "must be empty" unless university.nil?
  end
end
```

It isn't the prettiest, but it should to work.

Comment: Great! just a simple fix, it should be 'validate', with out the final 's'. And I think that it should add an error msj to 'self.errors' if university.nil? is false.